# If parameter is array return array of values otherwise return value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to allow a `string` or an array of `string`s as a parameter. Depending on whether a `string` or an array of `string`s have been passed I want to return either a value or an array of values.

```
function(input: string | string[]): inputIsArray ? returnValue[] : returnValue {}
```

How can I write proper types for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I'd use [overloads](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) (but conditional types *can* be used, see below). In this example, I've used `number` for `returnType` but of course that's just for the example:

```
function example(input: string): number;
function example(input: string[]): number[];
function example(input: string | string[]): number | number[] {
    if (Array.isArray(input)) {
        return (<string[]>input).map(str => Number(str));
    }
    return Number(<string>input);
}

const result1 = example("42");         // `result1`'s type is `number`
const result2 = example(["42", "67"]); // `result2`'s type is `number[]`
```

*([on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20example(input%3A%20string)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0Afunction%20example(input%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20example(input%3A%20string%20%7C%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20number%20%7C%20number%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(Array.isArray(input))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(%3Cstring%5B%5D%3Einput).map(str%20%3D%3E%20Number(str))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Number(%3Cstring%3Einput)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result1%20%3D%20example(%2242%22)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%60result1%60's%20type%20is%20%60number%60%0D%0Aconst%20result2%20%3D%20example(%5B%2242%22%2C%20%2267%22%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%60result2%60's%20type%20is%20%60number%5B%5D%60))*

Note that the third one of those is just the *implementation signature*. The only valid call signatures for `example` there are the first two.

---

Re your comment asking if this is possible with conditional types, off-site I pinged [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir), one of SO's experts on TypeScript. He said he'd seen the question and was about to post the overloads answer when he saw I had :-), and that he'd also use overloads for this — but it *is* possible with conditional types if you want to do it that way, and doing so opens up a third call signature. Here's what he came up with:

```
function example<T extends string | string[]>(input: T): T extends string ? number : number[];
function example(input: string | string[]): number | number[] {
    if (Array.isArray(input)) {
        return (<string[]>input).map(str => Number(str));
    }
    return Number(<string>input);
}

const result1 = example("42");         // `result1`'s type is `number`
const result2 = example(["42", "67"]); // `result2`'s type is `number[]`
```

*([on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20example%3CT%20extends%20string%20%7C%20string%5B%5D%3E(input%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20extends%20string%20%3F%20number%20%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20example(input%3A%20string%20%7C%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20number%20%7C%20number%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(Array.isArray(input))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(%3Cstring%5B%5D%3Einput).map(str%20%3D%3E%20Number(str))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Number(%3Cstring%3Einput)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result1%20%3D%20example(%2242%22)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%60result1%60's%20type%20is%20%60number%60%0D%0Aconst%20result2%20%3D%20example(%5B%2242%22%2C%20%2267%22%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%60result2%60's%20type%20is%20%60number%5B%5D%60))*

Notice how introducing `T` lets us use it both in the type of the parameter and the (conditional) type of the return value. (That was the key part I missed trying to apply conditional types to this.)

He pointed out that the conditional types version opens up a third way to call it: With an argument whose type is `string | string[]`, not one or the other:

```
declare const value: string | string[];
let result3 = example(value) // `result3`'s type is `number | number[]`. Would not have worked with overloads.
```

*([on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20example%3CT%20extends%20string%20%7C%20string%5B%5D%3E(input%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20extends%20string%20%3F%20number%20%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20example(input%3A%20string%20%7C%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20number%20%7C%20number%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(Array.isArray(input))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(%3Cstring%5B%5D%3Einput).map(str%20%3D%3E%20Number(str))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Number(%3Cstring%3Einput)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result1%20%3D%20example(%2242%22)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%60result1%60's%20type%20is%20%60number%60%0D%0Aconst%20result2%20%3D%20example(%5B%2242%22%2C%20%2267%22%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%60result2%60's%20type%20is%20%60number%5B%5D%60%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20value%3A%20string%20%7C%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20result3%20%3D%20example(value)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%60result3%60's%20type%20is%20%60number%20%7C%20number%5B%5D%60.%20Would%20not%20have%20worked%20with%20overloads.))*

So if you want that third call signature, you can use conditional types to get it. Otherwise, overloads provide just the first two signatures.

Comment: Don't you see a clever way of writing types, I was assuming something like this:

`function myFunc<S = string[] | string>(input: S): S extends string[] ? number[] : number;`

Comment: Btw awesome to get a comment from you again T.J. I believe I already got comments for you >10 years ago :)

Comment: @Lukas - I'm afraid I don't know of a way to define the return type in terms of whether the parameter type is an array (other than using overloads :-) ).

Comment: @Lukas - I pinged one of the TypeScript experts I know about this. See the updated answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, that is great to know! It actually works in my code too!